# Where can I see my Lambda functions on AWS after I deploy with serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I've deployed two functions using the amazon provider. they are working great and I can hit the API endpoint. Where on the AWS website can I see and manage the logs/instances of these? I cannot find them anywhere in the Lambda section.

Answer (score 0):

There's a drawer on the left side of the Lamba page... open it up and click functions...